# devise_scope in namespaces, rails api_only mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm trying to remove the obsolete routes of devise, in my api_only rails setup. However i'm in a fuss about how to define them properly with devise_scope. I have the following routes.rb:

```
# config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do    
  namespace :api do
    namespace :users do
      devise_scope :user do
        resource :confirmations, only: %i[create show], format: false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which refers to the confirmations_controller that contains custom json renders instead of the typical respond_with:

```
# app/controllers/api/users/confirmations_controller.rb

module Api
  module Users
    class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
      # POST /resource/confirmation
      def create
        self.resource = resource_class.send_confirmation_instructions(resource_params)
        yield resource if block_given?

        if successfully_sent?(resource)
          # respond_with({}, location: after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
          render json: { status: 201 }, status: :created
        else
          # respond_with(resource)
          render json: { status: 422, errors: resource.errors.keys },
                 status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end

      # GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef
      def show
        self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
        yield resource if block_given?

        if resource.errors.empty?
          set_flash_message!(:notice, :confirmed)
          # respond_with_navigational(resource) { redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
          render json: { status: 200 }, status: :ok
        else
          # respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity) { render :new }
          render json: { status: 422, errors: resource.errors.keys },
                 status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As can be seen in the routes.rb I only need the create and show endpoints of confirmations. However the current definition results in the following error when running rspec:

```
 Failure/Error: get api_users_confirmations_path, params: { confirmation_token: 'incorrect_token'  }

 AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
   Could not find devise mapping for path "/api/users/confirmations?confirmation_token=incorrect_token".
   This may happen for two reasons:

   1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:

     devise_scope :user do
       get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
     end

   2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
      If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:

      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

Which tends mostly to the missing devise mapping, considering that the devise_scope is defined properly. However i'm not sure how to solve this properly without having to include the bindings in every devise controller. Is this doable from the routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried to use resources inside of devise_scope.

This is how I have defined it.

```
devise_scope :user do
  delete 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

This is how I have defined in one of my application

```
    devise_for :users, path: 'api/v1/accounts', controllers: {
        :registrations      => 'api/v1/accounts/registrations',
        :sessions           => 'api/v1/accounts/sessions',
        :passwords          => 'api/v1/accounts/passwords'
      }

devise_scope :user do
    get  '/sessions/new' => "sessions#new", :as => :new_sessions
    get  '/sessions/forgot_password' => "sessions#forgot_password", :as => :forgot_password
    post '/validate_referral_code' => 'validates#validate_referral_code', as: :validate_referral_code
    post '/validate_employment_code' => 'validates#validate_employment_code', as: :validate_employment_code
    post '/get_weather' => 'temperature#weather', as: :weather
    get '/fetch' => 'zip_codes#fetch', as: :fetch_zip_code
    post '/request_demo' => 'demos#create', as: :create
  end

namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      scope :accounts do
        resources :third_party_logins, only: [] do
          collection do
            get :action_name
          end
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: The thing to be noted here is that the devise scope is defined outside of the namespaces of the api that will be creating conflit with Devise resource namespace handling ! Thanks for your answer @Kedarnag !